# Is there a simple way to convert an HTML newsletter into a WP blog post?

Tags: html

I've been tasked with something that I suspect is not easily possible (keyword: easily).

I manage a WP-based news website and we also send a monthly newsletter using MailerLite. Each newsletter issue has a "read this in the browser" link which just lets them read the same newsletter online (hosted at ML) instead of in their email.

Now I've been asked to find a way to take those web-based HTML newsletters and convert them into a Post so that they can also be read like any other Post on the site.

I suggested a MUCH simpler method which is to PDF the newsletter and upload it to an archive where it can be downloaded, but was told that could be our *fallback* method if I can't figure it out.

I know that with a lot (a LOT) of manual work I could simply paste in all that HTML and ensure that referenced images are in the media library and the styles are imported too, but I'm trying to find as close to a "one click" method as possible.

I have been searching and haven't yet found a plugin that will do this (I did find methods for doing the reverse, converting a blog Post into an HTML newsletter, but it's not helpful in this situation), so I’m hoping maybe someone else will have gone through this and have a suggestion?